# imacros jave loop read new csv row?

Tags: javascript, firefox, scripting, imacros

if I use this code in javascript for imacros

`for(var i=0;i<10;i++)`

and put this at the beginning (i will be filling out 10 forms)

`macro +-= SET !DATASOURCE input.csv`

`macro +-= SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 7`

will every loop, read from the next row in my

`{{!COL1}} {{!COL2}} {{!COL3}}` ..etc

or do i have to put

`{{!LOOP}}` somewhere?

so... if i wanted to fill a form 10 times, would each loop read from the next csv row, if im just using

`for(var i=0;i<10;i++)`

Answer (score 1):

You can only switch rows like this in imacros, not columns.
try this code example:

```
    var load;
    load =  "CODE:";
    load +=  "set !extract null" + "\n"; 
    load +=  "SET !DATASOURCE input.csv" + "\n"; 
    load +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 7" + "\n"; 
    load +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{i}}" + "\n"; 
    load +=  "SET !extract {{!col1}}" + "\n";
    var load2;
    load2 =  "CODE:";
    load2 +=  "set !extract null" + "\n"; 
    load2 +=  "SET !DATASOURCE input.csv" + "\n"; 
    load2 +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 7" + "\n"; 
    load2 +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{i}}" + "\n"; 
    load2 +=  "SET !extract {{!col2}}" + "\n";
    var load3;
    load3 =  "CODE:";
    load3 +=  "set !extract null" + "\n"; 
    load3 +=  "SET !DATASOURCE input.csv" + "\n"; 
    load3 +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 7" + "\n"; 
    load3 +=  "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{i}}" + "\n"; 
    load3 +=  "SET !extract {{!col3}}" + "\n";
    for(i=1;i<10;i++){
    iimSet("i",i);
    iimPlay(load);
    var content=iimGetLastExtract(0);
    iimSet("i",i);
    iimPlay(load2);
    var content2=iimGetLastExtract(0);
    iimSet("i",i);
    iimPlay(load3);
    var content3=iimGetLastExtract(0);
...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also store the data from CSV with loading the whole CSV file in variable. Then you can use split() method to split by commas and store in individual variables. The code for this it too long but it's an idea if you want to use different approach.